# How to show Laravel Nova action without select any record from Nova Resource Listing/Index?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

[image]

As seen in the image below. When we select the record from the listing than action drop down appear. But I need to show it always, either user selects some record or not.

Answer (score 16):

I know this is old, but hopefully it helps somebody. The [Standalone Actions](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/actions/registering-actions.html#standalone-actions) is what you're looking for. Not sure if this was a feature when @VolkerRose posted his answer.

Place this at the bottom of your Nova Resource.

```
    public function actions(Request $request)
    {
        return [
                Actions\ImportSalesForceRecords::make()->standalone(),
        ];
    }
```

[image]

I was really wanting the action button to be right next to the create button, but this will work.

Comment: This should mention, that this will `disconnect` the `action button` from `databases` and always receive an empty array in its `handle` method. Source: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/actions/registering-actions.html#standalone-actions

Answer (score 3):

Maybe "Inline Actions" can help you out? (Which are not really adequate covered over at https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/actions/defining-actions.html.)

[image]

```php
class SomeAction extends Action
{
    public $showOnTableRow = true;

    // [...]
}
```

If you are trying to limit your actions visibility with the `canSee` method, there is an existing issue regarding Inline Actions: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/actions/defining-actions.html#action-visibility.